# Running two same assemblies in two different appdomains

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, appdomain

I want to know how to create two appdomains and then how to load the same assemblies into it.  After that i need to create an instance of someclass from each assembly which should be executed in it's own appdomain.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two exe which creates the instance of specific class you want and execute any other logic. Then As shown below you can create app domains and execute each exe in the defferent App Doman you created.

[Application Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173138%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
static void Main()
{
    // Create an Application Domain:
    System.AppDomain newDomain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewApplicationDomain");

    // Load and execute an assembly:
    newDomain.ExecuteAssembly(@"c:\HelloWorld.exe");

    // Unload the application domain:
    System.AppDomain.Unload(newDomain);
}
```